# Property validation in es6 classes

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-6, setter, es6-class

I need to validate properties before setting them in my class. I have defined setter methods for each property in the class as shown below:

```
class SetterDemo {
    constructor(document) {
        this.document = {
            _type: 'SetterDemo'
        };
        this.document.prop1 = document.prop1;
    }
    get prop1() {
        return this.document.prop1;
    }
    set prop1(value) {
        //validating data. This is just an example. My validations will be a lot complex
        if (!value) {
            throw 'Invalid data';
        }
        this.document.prop1 = value;
    }
}
```

This works well as long as I am doing this:

```
let instance1 = new SetterDemo({prop1: 'abc'});
instance1.prop1 = null; //Throws error. Good. Just like I want it to.
```

But when I do this:

```
let instance2 = new SetterDemo({prop1: null});
```

It is creating an instance without throwing an error. I want it to throw an error because "prop1" is invalid. Its seems that the setter method for prop1 is not getting invoked in the constructor. Is there a way where I can use the setter method in the constructor? Or is there a way where I can use a common validator function in both the my setter method and constructor?

**Note:** I have tried creating some validator functions outside my class and used them in the setter as well as in the constructor. This works like I want to, but it does not seem like the right way. Here is the code for it:

```
class SetterDemo {
    constructor(document) {
        this.document = {
            _type: 'SetterDemo'
        };
        if (!validateProp1(document.prop1)) {
            throw 'Invalid data';
        }

        this.document.prop1 = document.prop1;
    }
    get prop1() {
        return this.document.prop1;
    }
    set prop1(value) {
        if (!validateProp1(value)) {
            throw 'Invalid data';
        }
        this.document.prop1 = value;
    }
}

module.exports = SetterDemo;

// -- Private Functions -- //
//validator function for prop1
function validateProp1(value) {
    if (!value) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `else if (value.prop1 === null ) { throw "Err."; }` i guess you need to add this

Comment: This line is the issue: `this.document.prop1 = document.prop1;` it needs to be `this.prop1 = document.prop1;`. FWIW external validation is completely fine, just be consistent. Your bug is that your are bypassing the setter in the constructor though.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Your comment is what I was looking for. It had crossed my mind but I was not sure and was experimenting on it and now it is working as expected. Thank you. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
this.document.prop1 = document.prop1;
```

it needs to instead be

```
this.prop1 = document.prop1;
```

What is happening is that you are bypassing the setter in the constructor.